# How can store data to my internal storage in Flutter not path_providers

Tags: android, flutter, dart, local-storage, storage

I want to create a Directory like we have for whatsapp in my internal storage. I've checked path_providers but thats not exactly what I need.

I want to create a directory in our default internal storage where the Android, Downloads, Pictures are all present and store data to that folder.
As asked the path I need is `/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder`.

Please don't suggest path_providers or shared_preferences. I need to create a folder in the path where the File manager in our phone opens up.

Is it possible? If yes, please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: `Directory like we have for whatsapp in my internal storage.` Please mention full path. I have no idea where you are talking about.

Comment: `I need to create a folder in the path where the File manager in our phone opens up.` There are hundreds of such apps and a lot show rubbish at startup.

Comment: As a programmer you should mention full path where you want to create a folder.

Comment: I've added the path `/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder` to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to do this in Native Java
as

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("myFolderName");
```

Just check if the directory already exists and create if not exists!